# jQuery Click executes only once inside for loop. Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, tampermonkey

Trying to change a text area to a car and then click a button to execute something and then rinse and repeat for a new car until we've done it for all cars.

```
var index;
var cars = ["car1" , "car2" , "car3"]
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
for(index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    x[0].innerHTML = cars [index];
    jQuery('#someID').click();
}
```

This just goes through all cars and then clicks the button once we reach the last car.

If I take out the x[0] line and just have clicked it, it does in fact click 3 times once for each item in the array, but the site I'm using pops a window up saying
 please insert a car each time we click with nothing, put inside the textarea.

Why does it work when its blank, but not when I try to edit the textarea?

Comment: I'm not sure your click handler is going to work that way that it is; you may have to use the jQuery('body').on('click', '#someID') form of the event handler. I don't quite understand what it happening with the pop-up window you are referring to.

Comment: You know how alert("this pops open") shows on the screen? It alerts me that I need to insert text. Sorry for not clarifying. I'll try using that instead. EDIT: With "jQuery('body').on('click', '#someID')" it doesn't click the button at all.

Comment: I see what you're saying. You can monkey patch to avoid that.        window.alert = function() {};    Basically anytime alert gets called it will call this empty function instead. Which, given my hatred of alerts, should be used everywhere.

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't understand how I can edit the textarea and have it click the button per car string in my array.

Comment: I believe I totally misunderstood your original issue. I apologize. So, you're trying to get jQuery to click the button based on an event that's happening with the cars? Is there any reason not to effect the behavior directly? Maybe that's what you were originally asking. Would you be willing to load up what you're trying to do in jsBin? http://jsbin.com/?html,output

Comment: I'm trying to make a TamperMonkey Script to automate a task for me on a site. To go through an array of strings to auto input a string in a text area of the site and then click a button, and continue on with the next string. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work for you.

```
var cars = ["car1" , "car2" , "car3"]
for(var index = 0; index < cars.length; index++) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].textContent += cars[index];
  document.getElementById("someId").click()
}
```